# Does the google-cloud-storage ruby gem support bulk operations?

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to figure out if [the gem](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/tree/main/google-cloud-storage) supports bulk operations. I don't see any mention of it in [the API docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1), but GCS does look like it does support [batch requests](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/batch). I'm thinking maybe it's not implemented in the gem?

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported yet, however there is a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142641783). The developer team is aware and working on this issue, but there is no ETA for its release.

I recommend you to [subscribe](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe) to the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142641783) for the feature request, this way you receive an email each time there is any new update.
Also, post a comment there about why it would be helpful. Additionally, please notice the more [stars](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#what-to-expect) the issue tracker has, the more likely it is to be implemented.

Comment: Thanks Andres! Anything I can say to motivate the team? We would really love this feature ;) The performance gains for us would likely be pretty awesome, since uploading assets one at a time is taking up the majority of our operation's time right now. :pray:

Comment: @MiaZ, I recommend you to [subscribe](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe) to the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142641783) for the feature request, this way you receive an email each time there is any new update. 
Also, post a comment there about why it would be helpful. Additionally, please notice the more [stars](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#what-to-expect) the issue tracker has, the more likely it is to be implemented.